# How do you handle multiple keys at once with the keyboard module in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard-events

I am writing a program that depends on the Windows keyboard hooks. I currently just hook the control key to stop the SAPI speech, like such.

```
import keyboard
import speech

def onPressReaction(event):
    if event.name=="ctrl":
        speech.cancel()

def initialize():
    keyboard.hook(onPressReaction)
```

But my question is: let's say I wanted to add a command (e.g. control+shift+t), for SAPI to speak the current foreground window title. How would I go about checking for all those keys at once?

Comment: In the `keyboard` module's [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardadd_hotkeyhotkey-callback-args-suppressfalse-timeout1-trigger_on_releasefalse) it says you can do something like that by using a format like `ctrl+shift+a` for the `hotkey` argument.

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.hook): keyboard.is_pressed:`is_pressed(57) #-> True
is_pressed('space') #-> True
is_pressed('ctrl+space') #-> True`

Comment: This only works with something that isn't hook, from the looks of it.

Comment: Implement a state machine that accepts the sequence(s) that lead to the desired keyboard shortcut.

Comment: How would you suggest? import queue and queue the keys or...